# Elasticsearch 1.7 logrotation crashes for clusters with low logging

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j

We have specific active Elasticsearch clusters whose logrotation crashes frequently.

We have more than 100 elasticsearch clusters and just some specific keep crashing their logrotation. After investigation, I have come to conclude that it has something to do with the small amount of logging to those clusters. Some days there are no logs in those clusters.

I have two suspects:

1. either log4j.properties minimum size, which I could not locate ( as a file ) somewhere in the installation. Thus I wonder whether it is overridden by something or has some kind of defaults if not present.
2. The conversion pattern of the logs, which looks something like this:

   file: type: extrasRollingFile file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log rollingPolicy: timeBased rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz layout: type: pattern conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

The reason i suspect the logging pattern (2),is because some days there are no logs.So maybe if it goes through a day that cannot rotate,it remains crashed for the rest days as well, and needs a service restart.

**So do you believe it is the small size of the logs to blame or the absence of logs that blocks log rotation?**

**log4j or logging.yml?**

Thanks!